# ASP.NET error handling - not detecting the right error type in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, exception

I have some custom error classes defined, each with their own functionality (not shown):

**Exceptions.cs**

```
public abstract class MyAppException : Exception {
  //...
}
public class ValidationException : MyAppException {
  //...
}
public class AccessDeniedException : MyAppException {
  //...
}
```

Now in the codebehind of a blank page I have:

**test.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

My intention is to catch this at the application level:

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var exc = Server.GetLastError();
  if (exc is MyAppException) ((MyAppException)exc).Log();
}
```

But by adding a breakpoint I find that `exc is MyAppException` evaluates as `false`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the InnerException:

```
if (exc.InnerException is MyAppException)
```

It's the `System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError` method that wraps the actual exception into an `HttpUnhandledException`.